# NullPointExeption when try to put variable to object in Java

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I create object which contain feature geometry and attributes:

```
public class Feature {
Feature(String wkt) {
this.wkt = wkt;
}

private HashMap<Column, String> columnMap;
private String wkt;

public String getWKT() {
return wkt;
}
public void addAttribute(Column column, String value) {
columnMap.put(column, value);
}
public String getAttribute(String column) {
return columnMap.get(column) ;
}
public Map<Column, String> getAttributes(){
    return columnMap;

}
}
```

Wkt is a geometry. ColumnMap is object contain a attributes as HashMap:

```
public class Column {

private String columnName;

Column(String columnName) {
  this.columnName = columnName;
}

public String getName() {
  return columnName;
}
}
```

Now i says:

```
columnList = new ArrayList<Column>(columns);

......

Feature feature= new Feature(WKT);
for(int p=0;p<columnList.size();p++){
for(int k=0;k<=ViewObject.getMIDInfo(totalObjects).length;k++){
   if(p==k){
       System.out.println("Column  "+columnList.get(p).getName()+"  Value  "+ ViewObject.getMIDInfo(totalObjects)[k].toString());
      //feature.addAttribute(columnList.get(p), ViewObject.getMIDInfo(totalObjects)[k].toString());
   }
}
}
```

And get output:

```
Column  id  Value  22
Column  kadnumm  Value  "66-41-0707001-19"
```

So how i understand `columnList` and `ViewObject.getMIDInfo(totalObjects)` is not empty. After this i change :

```
//feature.addAttribute(columnList.get(p), ViewObject.getMIDInfo(totalObjects)[k].toString());
```

to:

```
feature.addAttribute(columnList.get(p), ViewObject.getMIDInfo(totalObjects)[k].toString());
```

And get exeption:

```
Column  id  Value  22
java.lang.NullPointerException
at objects.Feature.addAttribute(Feature.java:18)
at objects.MIFParser.findRegion(MIFParser.java:181)
at objects.MIFParser.instanceNextObject(MIFParser.java:66)
at Read.main(Read.java:40)
```

How i understand NullPointerException means that i try to use empty objects? Whats wrong?
P.s. Sorry my english can be terrible especially with title .

**UPDATE**

Okey i add this: `this.columnMap = new HashMap<Column, String>();` in FEature class constructor.

But now i try to do:

```
System.out.println(feature.getAttribute("id")+" "+feature.getAttribute("kadnumm"));
```

and output:

```
null null
```

What can be wrong?

Comment: I'm voting for every other answer, CID they're all the same. Just putting it out there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`addAttribute` tries to put something on `columnMap`, but you don't create `columnMap` anywhere. You need to add to your `Feature` constructor:

```
Feature(String wkt) {
    this.wkt = wkt;
    this.columnMap = new HashMap<Column, String>(); // <=== The new bit
}
```

...or add an initialization to your declaration:

```
private HashMap<Column, String> columnMap = new HashMap<Column, String>();
//                        The new bit--- ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Just declaring the member isn't sufficient, the member just refers to an object, and starts off `null`. You need to create the object for it to refer to and assign that object to it.

Comment: `this.columnMap = new HashMap<Column, String>();` this help. But i get another problem with it. Please look at my question update.

Answer (score 3):

You didnt initialize your columnMap:

```
private HashMap<Column, String> columnMap = new HashMap<Column, String>();
```

Answer (score 2):

columnMap object is not initialized when you create a new instance of Feature. So it is null when you call `columnMap.put(column, value);` in `addAttribute`

Answer (score 2):

instead of

```
private HashMap<Column, String> columnMap;
```

do

```
 private HashMap<Column, String> columnMap = new HashMap<Column, String>();
```

Answer (score 1):

You must initialize the map:

```
private HashMap<Column, String> columnMap = new HashMap<Column, String>();
```